# Adding table and style to PHP echo code

Tags: php, css, search, html-table

I'm trying to add a table `<table border='2' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000;width:400'>` and style from css `<div class='results'>` to my PHP echo code here it is:

```
        echo "    
                            <div class='results'>
                            <table border='2' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000;width:400'>
                            <tr>
            <div class='title'><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></div>
            <div class='url'><font color='green' size='2'>$url</font></div>
            <div class='desc'>$desc</div>
                            </div></tr></table></div>
            <br />
            ";
```

I want to add the style and table into that php code, it doesn't work, how else should I write it.. you can see the `<table..>` and the `<div..>` it doesn't do anything to the echo, the code appears on the page with no table and no style added to it..

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work as I wrote it"? Be more specific.

Comment: What _doesn't work_ means?

Comment: no idea what the question is about; do elaborate

Comment: Have you this code inside `<?php` and `?>`? Is it in `.php` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<div>` tags, you need to use `<td>` tags inside `<tr>` in table:

```
echo"<div class='results'>
    <table border='2' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000;width:400'>
        <tr>
            <td class='title'><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></td>
            <td class='url'><font color='green' size='2'>$url</font></td>
            <td class='desc'>$desc</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this , Convert div to td

```html
echo "    <div class='results'>
    
    <table border='2' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000;width:400'>
            <tr>
            <td class='title'><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></td>
            <td class='url'><font color='green' size='2'>$url</font></td>
            <td class='desc'>$desc</td>
                            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect one.

Try this

```
<?php 
$url="URL";
$title="TITLE";
$desc="DESC";

echo "<div class='results'>
         <table border='2' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000;width:400'>
         <tr>
          <td><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></td>
          <td><font color='green' size='2'>$url</font></td>
          <td>$desc</td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         </div>";
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eSu6uc)

Comment: Yes, if you correct the OP's mistake, it works fine. This is not very helpful...